# How do i align a text?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a product detail page. In description, I have a text that talks about the product. When breaking the line, I want it to start from the first word of the description. In the photos, there is my example and the example of how I want it to look

html:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">    
    {%if produto.image %}
        <img class="img-produto" src='/media/{{produto.image}}'>
    {% else%}
        <img class="img-produto" src="{% static '/img/not-found-product.jpg' %}">
    {%endif%}
</div>
<div class="col">
    <h1>{{ produto.produto_nome }}</h1>
    <hr>       
    <h2>R${{ produto.preco }}</h2>
    <p class="p-descricao">Descrição</p>
    <span class='p-text-descricao'>{{produto.descricao}} asdasdasd as d asdasdasdasdasdasa s asdasd asd sads </span>
</div>
```

```
.p-descricao{
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 display: inline;
 padding-right: 50px;
 color: #565656;
}

.p-text-descricao{
   color: #4f4f4f;

}
```

[image: My exemple]

[image: example I want it to look like]

Comment: Wrap your `p` and `span` in a wrapper `div` and give them `display:flex` properties so that they are shown in a row side by side

Comment: @PratikWadekar Don't give answers in comments.

Answer (score 1):

1. Wrap `<p>` and `<span>` by a `<div>`
2. Set the display style to `display: flex;`.
3. Use `justify-content: space-between;` to space two children.
4. Finally, use `align-items: baseline;` to vertically align the chilren tags.

```css
.p-attribute-group {
  width: 50%;
  /* You may need to modify width to fit your project */
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: row; 
    default flex-direction is row, so it's not neccessary 
    to write this line if you need row flex
    */
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
  /* 
    to make sure children is vertically aligned
    when flex-direction is row
    */
}
```

```html
<div class="p-attribute-group">
  <p class="p-descricao">Descrição</p>
  <span class='p-text-descricao'>asdasdasd as d asdasdasdasdasdasa s asdasd asd sads </span>
</div>
```

[The screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNCgc.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap both the `<p>` and `<span>` tags with a div with the following css:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
```

Working example:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.p-descricao{
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 display: inline;
 padding-right: 50px;
 color: #565656;
}

.p-text-descricao{
   color: #4f4f4f;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="p-descricao">Descrição</p>
    <span class='p-text-descricao'>gfdsgfdsgfdsgfdsgfdgfdsgfdsgfdssadsafdgfdsagfdgfdgfsdsasasasa asdasdasd as d asdasdasdasdasdasa s asdasd asd sads </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `p` and `span` in a wrapper `div` and give them `display:flex` properties so that they are shown in a row side by side